# Match a chunk of text inside <p></p> where certain tags repeat more than 2 times

Tags: html, regex

I'm struggling to find a solution to this.

I would like to match any chunk of text inside `<p></p>` tags that contains more than 2 `<a></a>` tags

Here's an example

```
<p style=""> (Reporting by Jason Lange; Additional reporting by <a href="http://blogs.reuters.com/search/journalist.php?edition=us&amp;n=alistairbell&amp;">Alistair Bell</a>, <a href="http://blogs.reuters.com/search/journalist.php?edition=us&amp;n=eric.walsh&amp;">Eric Walsh</a> and <a href="http://blogs.reuters.com/search/journalist.php?edition=us&amp;n=peter.cooney&amp;">Peter Cooney</a>; Editing by Ros Russell and <a href="http://blogs.reuters.com/search/journalist.php?edition=us&amp;n=eric.beech&amp;">Eric Beech</a>)</p>
```

I'm trying to work out a regex code that would match this whole chunk of text inside `<p> </p>` tags, but the only determinant is the amount of `<a></a>` TAGS, I mean I've no idea what's the text is like.

Here's the regex code I have tried:

```
<p.*?>(\s+|\n+|)((.*?|)<a.*?>(.*?|)</a>(.*?|)){2,}(\s+|\n+|)</p>
```

It doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1364007) to "[*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1364007)".

Comment: Why simply `<p.*?>(.*?)</p>` isn't sufficient? Do you need to exclude `<a>`s or `</a>`s?

Comment: `|` and then also `()` is not necessary in `(.*?|)`. `<p.*?>` is not good - use `[^>]` instead of `.`.

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean? What happens? What language or tool are you testing this regex with?

Comment: @hata Because that ignores the "that contains more than 2 `<a></a>` tags" requirement.

Comment: "Have you tried using an XML parser instead?"

Comment: @Dukeling Ok, I see that he want to exclude anchor tags. Then, I would use 2-pass regex. 1st: `<p.*?>(.*?)</p>`; 2nd: `<\{0,1}a.*?>` for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to address this entire problem by parsing the html into a DOM and not by using a regexp.

If you must you can try something along the lines of this (there are some edge cases that will not work with this solution):

```
<p[^>]*>(.*?<a[^>]*>.*?<\/a[^>]*>.*?){2,}<\/p[^>]*>
```

This will match an opening `<p>`, then text containing `<a>` and `<\a>` at least twice and then the closing `</p>`

Comment: It will also, when it doesn't find 2 `<a>` tags, run straight past the `</p>`, into the next `<p>` and continue from there. It also won't work if the `<p>` tag contains another `<p>` tag.

Comment: you're right. In general it is impossible to correctly parse an hierarchical structure with a regexp. There are also other edge cases such as <p><a></a></p><p><a></a></p>. It would make the regex very complicated to make sure there's no closing </p> in the middle. This is why it's probably better to address this entire problem by parsing the html into a dom and not by using a regexp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/^<p.*(?=(\<\/a>).*(\<\/a>)).*<\/p>$/mg
```

I'm counting the  (I'm assuming that the html is properly formed)

https://regex101.com/r/oK4pM4/1